# Exposing installed, built libraries from external cmake project to parent

Tags: c++, cmake

I have added a project via Externalproject_Add and it compiles and installs fine. How do I get a list of all the targets that this externalproject_add exposes to my parent project?

On top of that, I want to manually expose a target to the parent. This external project does not install the static lib I need by default, I had to rsync it to the install dir. I'd like to expose that rsync'd static lib to the parent CMake context.

I suppose it needs to be exposed before it gets installed and then the parent context can get at it during the build step. Any parent context that wanted to use the library would have to depend upon the exposed library. I am just unsure of how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: "How do I get a list of all the targets that this externalproject_add exposes to my parent project?" - That list is **empty**. A subdproject included via `ExternalProject_Add` expose **none targets and variables** to the parent project. This is one of the key feature of `ExternalProject_Add`. If you want to use targets of the subproject, then include it via `add_subdirectory` into your project.

Comment: ah, or add_library if I want to manually expose one of the built static libraries?

Comment: In the main project you may create IMPORTED library target, and fill its properties for refer to the library built by `ExternalProject_Add`. This is recommended approach, but when filling the properties of IMPORTED library you should rely on where actualy this 3d party package installs binaries and headers.